# Jpa Repository findAll method which exceptions

Tags: spring, jpa

I am using JPA Repository. And as you know there are some standard implementations e.g. save, update or also findAll()  . I really like jpa but one thing really strikes. Even on the official website there are no hints which Exceptions are getting thrown by these functions. see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html

I do not think findAll() will throw a lot of Exceptions. Of course there will be one if database connection is lost, but there should be no others.

So for any database method there could be an exception so this always has to be handled separately in my service, right ?

Answer (score 1):

No you don't have to handle the Exceptions. Exceptions thrown in the Repository will be RuntimeExceptions and they will automatically rollback the transaction.

That's exactly what you want at this point.

On the other side you have a connection pool that will handle lost connections. So also there is no need for any Exception handling on your side.

Comment: You are right. All exceptions thrown by JPA extend RuntimeException . Ok. But still I need to handle these exceptions because the user wants to get an appropriate error message if let's say he wants to save a form but then on the server side there will be an exception. So I still need to know what kind of exception is thrown by e.g. findAll() method but there is no documentation for this somehow. I just know that all throw the base class  DataAccessException

Comment: The exception come from the underlying JPA. So you might checkout these exceptions: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/package-summary.html But if you get and exception from that layer it's most of the time a programming error. And you can display a generic error message.

Comment: it can also be client error. If someone wants to enter a duplicate key then there will be duplicate Exception. So I have to send this to the user so he knows what he did wrong. Also let's say the database crashes, all jpa methods will throw exceptioin and I can print to client "database not available"  error. As far as I know all JPA exceptions inherit from DataAccessException

Comment: No DataAccessException encloses the JPA exception but you can get it by calling getCause

Comment: For the first use case IMHO this is programming error because there should be a check before trying to insert the data. 2 If the DB crashes not only JPA but also the connection pool will no longer work. So this will result in several exceptions.

Comment: you are right. When I call getCause() on my spring DataIntegrityException I get the hibernate Exception which is hibernate.DataException . Then if I call getCause() on this I get jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation exception which finally gives me the real reason for the error. Based on this I could throw an appropriate Exception which clarifies the real reason for the Exception

Comment: But honestly I already prevent entering too many characters on the client side by setting attribute maxLength. So because I have this very general exception DataIntegrityException on the server side, I think I will not give a more specific error message on server side. I think it is enough to prevent this on the client side. Period. So i will not have a more specific exception

Comment: And the reason for not handling on server side more specifically but just to let it be DataIntegrityException is , let's say someone would use something else than hibernate than all my code would be not correct any more . So I just use spring exception. Full stop !

Comment: What do you think about my approach to only prevent it on the client, but not explicitly catch the right exception on the server ?